# What are the meanings of dotted and wavy lines in structural formulas?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula

So I came across this diagram,the other day:

[image: Bonds]

As  a chemistry student, I am well-versed with the dashed and wedged lines, but I was wondering what the wavy and the dotted line represent?

Comment: See also [_Graphical Representation Standards for Chemical Structure Diagrams_ (IUPAC Recommendations 2008)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200880020277) and [_Graphical Representation of Stereochemical Configuration_ (IUPAC Recommendations 2006)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac200678101897).

Answer (score 55):

> I was wondering what the wavy and the dotted line represent?

[image: Different bonds]

1. A **dashed** line indicates that the bond is extending **behind the plane** of the drawing surface
2. A **bold-wedged** line indicates that the bond is **protruding out** from the plane of the drawing surface
3. A **solid** line indicates that the bond exists **in** the plane of the drawing surface.
4. A **wavy** line indicates that the stereochemistry of the bond is **unknown**.
5. A **dotted** line indicates that the bond is not a full bond, it is only a **partial bond** as in a hydrogen bond or a partially formed or broken bond in a transition state. Also, as Mrigank Pawagi notes in the comments, the **dotted** line can be used along with the **solid** line to denote bonds that have partial double bond character due to resonance.
6. An **arrow** indicates a dative bond in which both electrons in the bond originate from one atom (not common)

Comment: As a side note, I would guide the OP to [their second virtual friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_formula).

Comment: I think dotted lines are more often used for intermolecular attractions and dashed lines for partial bonds.

Comment: A wavy line could also mean *isomerises rapidly*, e.g. a methyl group between two carbonyls.

Comment: The Dotted line is also used to denote bonds in resonance hybrids.

Comment: The arror is not uncommon at all, look at n-oxides

Answer (score 8):

The wavy line usually represents either that that part of the molecule is unimportant or that the stereochemistry at that specific position is unimportant (or unknown).

The dotted line usually represents intermolecular interactions, like hydrogen bonds. Dashed lines refer mostly to partial bonds such as in the transition state.