# Zigzag line in the structural formula of budesonide

Tags: structural-formula

Excuse me if this question is already answered, but while reading about [budesonide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budesonide), if came across a strange notation I have never seen. I am talking about zigzag line on the right sine. Can somebody, please, tell me what it is? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/yQWfl.png

Comment: I understand, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: more information in http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/what-are-the-meanings-of-dotted-lines-and-waves-in-structural-formulas