Coordination complex bond representations
It seems like there are various ways to represent coordinate covalent bond between ligands and transition metals which is very confusing to me. Can anyone tell me the difference between arrow bond, dashed bond, and regular solid bond? The followings are some examples. 



This question is similar to: What are the meanings of dotted and wavy lines in structural formulas?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/174299/different-types-of-bond-representations

If you narrowed it down to this unusual hashed bond it would be OK, I think. It's not the normal use mentioned in linked posts. If you got to it you should already be well aware what a covalent and/or dative bonds look like...
